# What does "2-2-4-niner" mean?

Tags: phraseology

In Avatar (2009), a man speaks to a pilot in a jet via radio:

> MAN :Valkyrie 1-6, copy...Valkyrie 1-6, you are clear for de-orbit
> burn at **2-2-4-niner**.
>
> Pilot: Copy, Venture Star. Go for de-orbit burn at **2-2-4-niner**.

What does "2-2-4-niner" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It refers to the time 22:49 (10:49 PM). In radio phraseology, every digit of a number is generally pronounced separately, and the number 9 is pronounced as "niner" (see [Why do English-speaking pilots and ATC say "Niner" instead of "Nine"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14875/why-do-english-speaking-pilots-and-atc-say-niner-instead-of-nine))

Often when referring to a specific time, only the number of minutes past the hour (in this case 49) are spoken, but the hour can be included as well in case there is any risk of doubt.

Comment: In US ATC all four digits are required.

Comment: @RetiredATC: check the [7110.65 2–4–17**c**4](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_4.html#VBJ21cJACK).

Comment: "Abbreviated time. The separate digits of the minutes only." Thanks for the correction. I always used c1. I can't even remember ever seeing c4.

Comment: Should be "Too Too Fower Niner"